# How do I make MySQL INSERT statements case-insensitive?

Tags: mysql, insert, h2, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I'm converting a database from H2 to MySQL, and the way H2 exports its tables they are all named IN_UPPERCASE_CHARACTERS. Does collation only apply do the data and am I stuck manually replacing table names?

Comment: Or, you could, y'know, just keep the original table names.  How many tables are we talking about?  A hundred?  Should take you about 15 minutes to rename them all by hand.

Comment: Relevant: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: No I can't. The CREATE TABLE statements were not compatible with MySQL so I let the application generate the tables. The application generated the MySQL tables in lowercase, and H2 exported in uppercase. It's actually 50 tables across 150,000 lines, hence why I don't want to rename them manually.

Comment: I want my table names to be in uppercase. SQL is translated to uppercase by default, so if you name your tables in lowercase you need to encase the names in quotations marks.

Would you rather write:

`SELECT "field1" FROM "table1" -- Table and field named in lowercase`

than

`SELECT field1 FROM table1  -- Table and field named in uppercase`

?

Comment: You can't put quotation marks around field names and table names, only backticks. Otherwise MySQL will interpret them as strings.

Comment: Upon what operating system platform is your MySQL server running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL collations apply only to contents of columns in the database. They are not a factor in your problem.

Column names, index names, etc, are all case-insensitive.

On Windows and Mac HFS, table names, like file names, are case-insensitive. On Linux / BSD / Unix, they, like file names, are case sensitive.

There are lots of things you can do to monkey around with all this.  See here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

If your MySQL database runs on a Windows (or Mac HFS) platform, you probably should do nothing. If it's on a *nix box, you might consider renaming the tables so they have the same case as your query code.

```
 RENAME `TABLENAME` TO `tablename`
```

Or, you can consider setting `lower_case_table_names=1`, renaming all your tables so they have lowercase names, and going from there.  That probably gives you the most resilient coding environment to use your database: it will make your table names in your code case-insensitive.  Of course if you have two different tables named `tablecase` and `TABLECASE` this won't work.